# Why does my inline styling not work with react?

Tags: css, reactjs, styling

I am trying to use inline styling react just to test it out, however my output is still not changing. The color should be changed to red. My terminal says it has also been styled successfully.

```
import React from 'react'

function App() {

  const styles = {
    color: 'red'
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
    <div>
    <h1 styles={styles}>Why does this not work</h1>

    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <p>Placeholder text </p>

    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <p>Placeholder text </p>

    <input type="checkbox" />
    <p>Placeholder text </p>

    <input type="checkbox" />
    <p>Placeholder text </p>

    </div>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is what I am getting back. The "Why does this not work" should change to red.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Should be `style={styles}` not `styles={styles}`